# Including a prebuilt shared object file in an NDK project

Tags: android, android-ndk, embedded-linux, shared-objects, android-ndk-r5

I am working on including a shared object file onto the Android OS image through the NDK project.

The android.mk file looks like this

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := Myaccessories
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libMyaccessories.so

include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

And I have added the "libMyaccessories.so" to the jni folder where the android.mk is located. On ndk-built, it results in error which is as below

```
Prebuilt       : libMyaccessories.so <= jni/
Install        : libMyaccessories.so => libs/armeabi/libMyaccessories.so
/home/Identive/Desktop/android-ndk-r7/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-strip: Unable to recognise the format of the input file `./libs/armeabi/libMyaccessories.so'
make: *** [libs/armeabi/libMyaccessories.so] Error 1
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: FYI xyz.so is not and shared object file. xyz.so ir shared library. object file is xyz.o file.

Comment: then how about adding the shared library file ???

Comment: Lawrence below has written what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Just put the .so file in your libs/armeabi/ subdirectory, and it should automatically be included as part of your build. Don’t mention it in LOCAL_SRC_FILES, as it’s not a source file.

If that library is being referenced from native code, not just Java code, you may need to list it in LOCAL_LDLIBS, but I’d be very surprised if this isn’t the default.

Comment: yet changing the android.mk file, ndk-build throws "Unable to recognize the  input format" kindly help me the android.mk file

Comment: Then your file is not really shared library for ARM. Where did you get your shared library from?