# NDK build error

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am trying to use a pre built library within my project...its name is libfreeimage.so...
I am not able to build it properly using the NDK-build....
The error log has been pasted here...
please help me in this regard...

```
flock@QS57:~/Desktop/android-imagefilter-ndk$ /home/flock/ANDROID/android-ndk-r8/ndk-build
Prebuilt       : libfreeimage.so <= jni/
Install        : libfreeimage.so => libs/armeabi/libfreeimage.so
/home/flock/ANDROID/android-ndk-r8/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-strip: Unable to recognise the format of the input file `./libs/armeabi/libfreeimage.so'
make: *** [libs/armeabi/libfreeimage.so] Error 1
make: *** Deleting file libs/armeabi/libfreeimage.so
flock@QS57:~/Desktop/android-imagefilter-ndk$
```

My android.mk file-

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libfreeimage
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libfreeimage.a
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := imageprocessing
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := imageprocessing.c
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libfreeimage
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -lm -llog -ljnigraphics

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [including a prebuilt shared object file in an NDK project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9205245/including-a-prebuilt-shared-object-file-in-an-ndk-project)

Comment: post you Android.mk file

Comment: Possible Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593987/android-ndk-linking

Comment: @codetiger...I am just using a prebuilt library freeimage.so and using it in the C code can you please help me how to modify the code and where to put this library so that I can make my project to work??Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated...thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use

```
include ($BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

instead of

```
include ($BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

This will give you the desired .a file, not the .so.